# Python: Time interval between two timestamps returns negative number

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to get time difference between `y` and `x`, it gives me -ve value in milliseconds.

```
from datetime import datetime
x = '2018-01-28 08:58:10.83'
y = '2018-01-28 08:58:10.144'

x_time = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') # 2018-01-28 08:58:10.830000
y_time = datetime.strptime(y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') # 2018-01-28 08:58:10.144000

diff = y_time - x_time
duration_milliseconds = round(diff.total_seconds() * 1000)
print(duration_milliseconds)  # -686
```

I'm getting `-686` as result but I expect `61`. What is gonig wrong here?

Comment: `x = "2018-01-28 08:58:10.083"` would work.

Comment: read document, you will get your answer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

The value `.83`is the decimal value of the timestamp `2018-01-28 08:58:10.83`. This timestamp can also be written as `2018-01-28 08:58:10.830`, and this value is larger than `2018-01-28 08:58:10.144`, just like `.830` is greater than `.144`.

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) (emphasis mine):

> %f is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available). When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and **zero pads on the right**.

"right" not "left". So `.83` is seen as `.830` you need:

```
x = "2018-01-28 08:58:10.083"
```

(`%f` is supposed to represent a floating point part starting with `.`, padding is from the right not left: ex: `0.1 == 0.10`)